# Async execution limiting the number of concurrent instances

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a simple collection which I'm looping through like this:

```
foreach (MyObject mo in myObjects)
{
   myObject.RunAcync();
}
```

`RunAsync` executes code in a separate thread, using `new Thread(()=>{ .. }).Start()`, it's not in my power to change the code of `RunAsync`. I need to limit the number of instances of `myObject` running concurrently to N (real numbers are 2..10). What is the efficient way to do that using `.NET4` and `c#`?

Comment: You problem is that how do you know how many of these RunAsync methods are still running or not?

Comment: Yes, one of the problems, I've no Complete event fired by individual instances...

Comment: With no way to tell what is done and what is still running, I don't see how you do what you want without modifying `RunAsync`.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie Makes sense, how would you go about this task if you implemented if from scratch?

Comment: Is there a non-async version of the method, e.g. `.Run()`.  If so you could wrap that one with your own code to make it asynchronous.  You could pass `myObject` to a method on some `RunScheduler` class, and `RunScheduler` kicks off the thread immediately and increments a count, unless the count is 20, in which case it adds them to a queue.  You need to be able to see when they finish to deincrement the counter and kick off the next one in the queue.

Comment: With what we have now (.NET 4) and what's imminent (now when you think about it, .NET 4.5), I would use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and return some sort of `Task` object from `RunAsync`.  You can then easily tell what is done and what is running, and use the built-in TPL load balancing to limit the number of running tasks.

Comment: @user1514042 Alternatively, if you had a non-async version of the method, you could also use the TPL's `Parallel.ForEach` to invoke the method and it would deal with load-balancing and run only enough of the methods at one time to avoid performance issues.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie Thanks, could you post your comment as answer I'll mark it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify `RunAsync`, with what we have now (.NET 4) and what's imminent (now when you think about it, .NET 4.5), I would use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and return some sort of `Task` object from `RunAsync`. You can then easily tell what is done and what is running, and use the built-in TPL load balancing to limit the number of running tasks. Alternatively, if you had a non-async version of the method, you could also use the TPL's [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) to invoke the method and it would deal with load-balancing and run only enough of the methods at one time to avoid performance issues