# Task based processing with a limit for concurrent task number with .NET 4.5 and c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352560/async-execution-limiting-the-number-of-concurrent-instances/12352930#12352930), could anyone post a barebone solution for the following task, targeting .NET 4.5 (and WPF UI on a bigger scale)?

Basically I'm looking for a functional analog of any torrent application implemented on .NET 4.5 and c#.

The task:

I have `IEnumerable<IProcessable>`, containing 1000 instances of `IProcessable`, `IProcessable` has `Process(int argument)` method, taking from 1 to 10 seconds to execute. I want to loop through the collection and process each instance of `IProcessable`, limiting the number of concurrently processed instances to N (1..10), number of max concurrent instances should be easily adjustable. Ideally I'd each `IProcessable` to report about the progress of Process completion, here's a prototype of Process (it probably needs to be converted to something rather than void in order to enable progress reporting):

```
void Process(int e)
{
   int progress = 0;
   ...Sleep for 100ms;
   int progress = 30;
   ...Sleep for 100ms;
   int progress = 50;
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Tudor the second one, however I don't see much difference as new threads only get created when IProcessable is getting processed, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to limit the number processed instances at a time, it seems like [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) would be a good solution. When you use it, you can specify [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx), which does that.

Comment: "Number of max concurrent instances should be easily adjustable". If you mean that it should be adjustable **during** processing, you should not use `Parallel.ForEach()` and instead use a multithreaded producer/consumer queue.