# Limiting the amount of concurrent tasks in .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, asynchronous

Observer the following function:

```
public Task RunInOrderAsync<TTaskSeed>(IEnumerable<TTaskSeed> taskSeedGenerator,
    CreateTaskDelegate<TTaskSeed> createTask,
    OnTaskErrorDelegate<TTaskSeed> onError = null,
    OnTaskSuccessDelegate<TTaskSeed> onSuccess = null) where TTaskSeed : class
{
    Action<Exception, TTaskSeed> onFailed = (exc, taskSeed) =>
    {
        if (onError != null)
        {
            onError(exc, taskSeed);
        }
    };

    Action<Task> onDone = t =>
    {
        var taskSeed = (TTaskSeed)t.AsyncState;
        if (t.Exception != null)
        {
            onFailed(t.Exception, taskSeed);
        }
        else if (onSuccess != null)
        {
            onSuccess(t, taskSeed);
        }
    };

    var enumerator = taskSeedGenerator.GetEnumerator();
    Task task = null;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (task == null)
        {
            try
            {
                task = createTask(enumerator.Current);
                Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(task.AsyncState, enumerator.Current));
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                onFailed(exc, enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            task = task.ContinueWith((t, taskSeed) =>
            {
                onDone(t);
                var res = createTask((TTaskSeed)taskSeed);
                Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(res.AsyncState, taskSeed));
                return res;
            }, enumerator.Current).TaskUnwrap();
        }
    }

    if (task != null)
    {
        task = task.ContinueWith(onDone);
    }

    return task;
}
```

Where `TaskUnwrap` is the state preserving version of the standard `Task.Unwrap`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task TaskUnwrap(this Task<Task> task, object state = null)
    {
        return task.Unwrap().ContinueWith((t, _) =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
                throw t.Exception;
            }
        }, state ?? task.AsyncState);
    }
}
```

The `RunInOrderAsync` method allows to run N tasks asynchronously, but sequentially - one after another. In effect, it runs the tasks created from the given seeds with the concurrency limit of 1.

Let us assume that the tasks created from the seeds by the `createTask` delegate do not correspond themselves to multiple concurrent tasks.

Now, I would like to throw in the maxConcurrencyLevel parameter, so the function signature would look like this:

```
Task RunInOrderAsync<TTaskSeed>(int maxConcurrencyLevel,
  IEnumerable<TTaskSeed> taskSeedGenerator,
  CreateTaskDelegate<TTaskSeed> createTask,
  OnTaskErrorDelegate<TTaskSeed> onError = null,
  OnTaskSuccessDelegate<TTaskSeed> onSuccess = null) where TTaskSeed : class
```

And here I am a bit stuck.

The SO has questions like these:

- [System.Threading.Tasks - Limit the number of concurrent Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks)
- [Task based processing with a limit for concurrent task number with .NET 4.5 and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366608/task-based-processing-with-a-limit-for-concurrent-task-number-with-net-4-5-and)
- [.Net TPL: Limited Concurrency Level Task scheduler with task priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315937/net-tpl-limited-concurrency-level-task-scheduler-with-task-priority)

Which basically propose two ways to attack the problem:

1. Using `Parallel.ForEach` with `ParallelOptions` specifying the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property value as equal to the desired max concurrency level.
2. Using a custom `TaskScheduler` with the desired `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` value.

The second approach doesn't cut it, because all the tasks involved must use the same task scheduler instance. For that, all the methods used to return a `Task` must have an overload accepting the custom `TaskScheduler` instance. Unfortunately, Microsoft is not very consistent with that respect. For instance, `SqlConnection.OpenAsync` does not accept such an argument (but `TaskFactory.FromAsync` does).

The first approach implies that I will have to convert tasks to actions, something like this:

```
() => t.Wait()
```

I am not sure it is a good idea, but I will be glad to get more input on that.

Another approach is to utilize `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny`, but that is messy.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

I would like to clarify the reasons for wanting the limit. Our tasks ultimately execute SQL statements against the same SQL server. What we want is a way to limit the amount of concurrent outgoing SQL statements. It is entirely possible that there will be other SQL statements executing concurrently from other pieces of code, but this one is a batch processor and could potentially flood the server.

Now, be advised, that although we are talking about the same SQL server, there are numerous databases on that same server. So, it is not about limiting the amount of open SQL connections to the same database, because the database may not be the same at all.

That is why doom's day solutions like `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()` are irrelevant.

Now, about `SqlConnection.OpenAsync`. It was made asynchronous for a reason - it might make a roundtrip to the server and thus might be subject to the network latency and other lovely side effects of distributed environment. As such it is no different than other async methods which do accept the `TaskScheduler` parameter. I tend to think that not accepting one is just a bug.

**EDIT 2**

I would like to preserve the asynchronous spirit of the original function. Hence I wish to avoid any explicit blocking solutions.

**EDIT 3**

Thanks to [@fsimonazzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357517/263693) I now have a working implementation of the desired functionality. Here is the code:

```
        var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrencyLevel);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        var enumerator = taskSeedGenerator.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            tasks.Add(sem.WaitAsync().ContinueWith((_, taskSeed) =>
            {
                Task task = null;
                try
                {
                    task = createTask((TTaskSeed)taskSeed);
                    if (task != null)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(task.AsyncState, taskSeed));
                        task = task.ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                            sem.Release();
                            onDone(t);
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    sem.Release();
                    onFailed(exc, (TTaskSeed)taskSeed);
                }
                return task;
            }, enumerator.Current).TaskUnwrap());
        }

        return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), _ => sem.Dispose());
```

Comment: BlockingCollection allows you to set a BoundedCapacity

Comment: Well, sure SqlConnection.OpenAsync doesn't have that option.  It isn't going to burn N threads.  In fact, good odds it doesn't consume *any*.  If your tasks are so drastically unruly that you have to provide this kind of guarantee then ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads() is the nuclear option.

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**.

Comment: @Blam - your reply would be a great answer if you provide the code.

Comment: That is why it was a comment not an answer.  See the documentation on MSDN.  There is a sample of using BoundedCapacity.   SO is not a code generation tool.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a semaphore to throttle the processing. Using the WaitAsync() method you get the asynchrony you expected. Something like this (error handling removed for brevity):

```
private static async Task DoStuff<T>(int maxConcurrency, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> createTask)
{
    using (var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            await sem.WaitAsync();
            var task = createTask(item).ContinueWith(t => sem.Release());
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Edited to remove bug where the semaphore could be disposed before all release operations had a chance to be executed.

Comment: Can the last `WhenAll` be replaced with `ContinueWhenAll` ?

Comment: If you have a continuation, they yes use ContinueWhenAll.

Comment: Thank you. Your approach turned out to be quite easy to implement - posted the code in **EDIT 3**.

Answer (score 5):

Already a lot of answers here. I want to address the comment you made in Stephens answer, about an example of using the TPL Dataflow to limit concurrency. Even tough you have left a comment in another answer of this question that you don't use the Task-based approach anymore for this it might help other people.

An example of using the `ActionBlock<T>` for this is:

```
private static async Task DoStuff<T>(int maxConcurrency, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> createTask)
{
    var ab = new ActionBlock<T>(createTask, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConcurrency });

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ab.Post(item);
    }

    ab.Complete();
    await ab.Completion;
}
```

More information about the TPL Dataflow can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The two best solutions available today are `Semaphoreslim` (as per [@fsimonazzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357517/263693)) and a TPL Dataflow block (i.e., [`ActionBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`TransformBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Both of those blocks have a [simple way to set the level of concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`Parallel` is not an ideal approach, because you would need to block on your asynchronous operations, using up a thread pool thread for each one.

Also, `TaskScheduler` will not work here. FYI, `TaskScheduler` *is* "inherited" through `async` methods as I describe on [my `async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). The reason it won't work for your problem is because task schedulers only control *executing* tasks, not *event* tasks - so, the SQL operations like `OpenAsync` don't "count" towards the concurrency limit.

Comment: Do you mind sketching the approach using the TPL Dataflow block?

Comment: See my answer in which I used the `ActionBlock<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of @fsimonazzi's answer without the SemaphoreSlim, as cool as that is.

```
private static async Task DoStuff<T>(int maxConcurrency, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> createTask)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (tasks.Count >= maxConcurrency)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            tasks.Clear();
        }
        var task = createTask(item);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of @scott-turner's answer, as cool as that is. His answer submits work in chunks of maxConcurrency and waits until each chunk completes in full before submitting the next chunk. This variation submits new tasks as needed to try and ensure maxConcurrency tasks are always in flight. It also demonstrates working with Task< T > instead of Task.

Note the benefit of this over the SemaphoreSlim variation is with SemaphoreSlim you need to await two different types of Task's - the semaphores and the work. That's problematic if work is of type Task< T > instead of Task.

```
    private static async Task<R[]> concurrentAsync<T, R>(int maxConcurrency, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task<R>> createTask)
    {
        var allTasks = new List<Task<R>>();
        var activeTasks = new List<Task<R>>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (activeTasks.Count >= maxConcurrency)
            {
                var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(activeTasks);
                activeTasks.Remove(completedTask);
            }
            var task = createTask(item);
            allTasks.Add(task);
            activeTasks.Add(task);
        }
        return await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
    }
```

Comment: I no longer use the Task based approach to concurrency and asynchrony. See my other question and the accepted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263695/how-to-constraint-concurrency-the-right-way-in-rx-net